# Why am I signed out of AEM 6 while dragging and dropping component on a Page?

Tags: adobe, aem

We have an existing site that is built and deployed in Adobe CQ5.5.

Now we are planning to migrate it to AEM 6. We have successfully installed the instance and deployed the site.

But when we try making any changes like adding a new component it does not allow the operation. It says something **"Your request could not be completed because you have signed out"**

Comment: is the authoring server accessed via dispatcher ?

Comment: @SharathMadappa Well I think so. But I am not very sure. What do you think could be the cause of the problem? I can tell the Server Management team about it. They are blaming us developers for the problem where as this is a CQ issue as our site has no signing in module...

Comment: try accessing the server directly via IP and by passing the dispatcher. This usually happens due to some clientlibs cache issue in the author dispatcher. If everything is fine when authoring via IP , clearing the cache on author dispatcher should fix the issue.

Comment: @SharathMadappa I don't know how to clear the author dispatcher. Can you help me with this? I'll try searching in the meanwhile myself. Worst case I'll just the Server Management Team about it

Comment: can you first confirm that the problem is not present when accessing the server directly via IP

Comment: @SharathMadappa : I access the Server via a domain name over the internet and have no access to the actual server location(IP as you said)

Comment: @SharathMadappa : I tried to run the Dispatcher flush under Tools/Replication/ Agents on Author, when I tried enabling it I got the same error "You are signed out".

Comment: I'd say that you get someone to confirm that the issue is not present when authoring via IP before you clear the clientlibs cache.

Comment: Agreed with @SharathMadappa. Also, you could also try clearing cache from `/var`.

Comment: @SharathMadappa you were right. I accessed the server directly and this issue was not present. Can you please tell me how to clear the Dispatcher Cache?

Comment: I have this issue after upgrading from AEM6.0 to AEM6.1. The author is behind a dispatcher. If I login using SSO using the dispatcher handler, then I see the error upon attempts to edit. The dispatcher cache is completely empty and does not cache anything for the author. If I login directly to the author skipping the dispatcher and the SSO, then I don't see the error and my edits take.

Comment: Here are the logs messages.*INFO* POST /content/redacted/en/jcr:content HTTP/1.1] com.adobe.granite.csrf.impl.CSRFFilter isValidRequest: empty CSRF token - rejecting
*INFO*  POST /content/redacted/en/jcr:content HTTP/1.1] com.adobe.granite.csrf.impl.CSRFFilter doFilter: the provided CSRF token is invalid

Answer (score 2):

See: http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/dispatcher/security-checklist.html#par_title

AEM 6.1 has cross-site request forgery security features that requires you to do a bit of work to allow the /bin/wcmcommand request to authenticate from the dispatcher.

To see what I mean, open up your dev tools and go to the Network tab. When you try the action, you should see a wcmcommand request:

[image: Instead of a status code of 200,]

I bet you are getting a status code of 401 or 403.

Follow the instructions I started this post with to fix this.

Good luck!

Comment: I went to `/system/console/configMgr.html` and clicked on Apache Sling Referrer Filter and added my Domain name in allowed hosts. But I still get the same error. Do I have to make some changes in the Dispatcher or is this a CQ related issue ?

Answer (score 1):

@bfosterscripps provided this link which was helpful.
https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/dispatcher/security-checklist.html#par_title

Just to follow-up. I faced this issue, and for us it was caused by a misconfiguration of the distpatcher. Adding a rule for "CSRF-Token" made the difference. You may also need to check that /libs/granite/csrf/token.json is not blocked.

```
/authorfarm {  
# client headers which should be passed through to the render instances
# (feature supported since dispatcher build 2.6.3.5222)
/clientheaders {
    ....
    "CSRF-Token"
}
```